# Container of objects with unique IDs

Tags: c++, c++11

This `ObjectSet` container adds new `Object`s with lowest possible unique ID. My implementation uses `std::set` for its sorting, but this convenience may not be required.

My two main questions are:

1. Is `std::set` generally a good and preferred solution for this problem?
2. In case of using `std::set`, can `ObjectSet::minId` be implemented with use of standard algorithms?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

class Object
{
    std::uint32_t id_;

public:
    explicit Object(std::uint32_t id) : id_(id) {}

    std::uint32_t const& id() const
    {
        return id_;
    }

    std::string name() const
    {
        return "Object" + std::to_string(id_);
    }

    bool operator<(Object const& other) const
    {
        return id_ < other.id_;
    }
};

class ObjectSet : std::set<Object>
{
public:
    void addObject()
    {
        insert(Object(minId()));
    }

    void removeObject(std::uint32_t id)
    {
        erase(Object(id));
    }

    std::uint32_t minId() const
    {
        if(empty())
            return 1;

        for(auto it1 = begin(), it2 = it1++; it1 != end(); ++it1, ++it2)
            if(it1->id() != it2->id() + 1)
                return it2->id() + 1;

        return rbegin()->id() + 1;
    }

    using Base = std::set<Object>;

    using Base::begin;
    using Base::cbegin;
    using Base::rbegin;
    using Base::crbegin;

    using Base::end;
    using Base::cend;
    using Base::rend;
    using Base::crend;
};

int main()
{
    ObjectSet objects;
    objects.addObject();
    objects.addObject();
    objects.addObject();
    objects.removeObject(2);
    objects.addObject();

    for(auto const& object : objects)
        std::cout << object.name() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me. The only glaring stylistic issue I see is that you *inherit from* `std::set` instead of *having a member of* that type. Inheriting from classes whose innards you don't personally control usually leads to issues with slicing and/or expecting-polymorphism-and-not-getting-it. However, since you're doing *private* inheritance, this is probably okay.

There are a couple of functional improvements you *might* want to make (but then again might not, because they're subtle).

(1) Your `Object` type has an `operator<` that does nothing but compare `id`s. That's unlikely to be useful in practice. But you need to have that "compare `id`s" operation so that you can make your sorted `set`. The solution is to pass a comparator to your `set`, like so:

```
class ObjectSet {
    static bool id_less(const Object& a, const Object& b) {
        return a.id() < b.id();
    }
    std::set<Object, decltype(&id_less)> items_;

  public:
    ObjectSet() : items_(id_less) {}

    // ...
};
```

This allows you to reclaim `Object::operator<` for some more appropriate semantics.

(2) Continuing with comparators... Every time I call `removeObject`, you construct a whole `Object` to pass to `erase`. This seems wasteful (assuming `Object` is a heavyweight type), and also counter-intuitive: what do you mean, `removeObject` calls the *constructor* of `Object`?! :)

[The solution requires C++14 or better,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536788/avoiding-key-construction-for-stdmapfind/24360490#24360490) because it depends on a particular overload of `std::set<T>::find()` that first showed up in C++14.

```
class ObjectSet
{
    static bool id_less(const Object& a, const Object& b) { return a.id() < b.id(); }
    static bool id_less(const Object& a, std::uint32_t b) { return a.id() < b; }
    static bool id_less(std::uint32_t a, const Object& b) { return a < b.id(); }

    struct Comparator {
        template<class T, class U>
        bool operator()(const T& a, const U& b) { return id_less(a, b); }
        using is_transparent = void;
    };

    std::set<Object, Comparator> items_;

    // ...

    void removeObject(std::uint32_t id)
    {
        items_.erase(items_.find(id));
    }
};
```

[(Wandbox link.)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NeebxYxyN30vLS4C)

Comment: One SO question interested me and I coded it kind of in haste. I'm not going to be using it anytime soon, but you gave me a few valuable advices. Thanks. I guess that that private inheritance is OK too - I don't want any polymorphism and sliscing is forbidden by that. If `std::set` was a member, I certainly wouldn't like the process of defining all the member functions and overloads.